# any way to use axis2 client web services w/o generating a stub class?

Tags: apache-axis

are there any approaches for leveraging a java interface file to call an axis web service w/o generating a stub class?  We control both sides (client and server).

Comment: +1 for a reasonable question. skaffman, your language bias is not relevant here. We all know what phil means.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use an "adhoc" client using [org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_5/api/org/apache/axis2/client/ServiceClient.html). It looks something like this.

```
import org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMContainer;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMFactory;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMNamespace;
import java.net.URL;


...
String endpoint = "http://wsendpoint.com/ServiceName"
 QName operation = new QName("http://namespace","WsRequest");               
             OMElement payload = buildPayload("requestdata");


 try{
                   ServiceClient sender= new ServiceClient(
                            null,
                            new URL(endpoint),
                            null,
                            null);
                   OMElement result = sender.sendReceive(operation,payload);
           logger.debug("response is:" + result.toString());                                   

                    }

             }catch (Exception e)  {
                 logger.debug("exception caught: " + e.getMessage());
             }
```